# Dynamic SELECT does not work using @param in GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to do the following:

```
SELECT   CASE 
             WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'day' THEN DAY
             WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'month' THEN MONTH
             WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'year' THEN YEAR
         END                                             AS TIME_FIELD,
FROM ...
GROUP BY YEAR, 
         CASE
              WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'day' THEN MONTH
              WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'month' THEN MONTH
         END,
         CASE
              WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'day' THEN DAY
         END
```

But it keeps saying that MONTH and DAY is invalid in the SELECT-List because it is not contained in an aggregate function.

How can I realize this?

Thanks, 
Felix

Comment: two issues, 1.) your CASE statement in your SELECT is not the same as your CASE statement in your GROUP BY, it should be 2.) you should QUOTE DAY, MONTH, YEAR with '' as these character fields e.g. 'DAY'.

Comment: Do the two CASE statements always have to be identical? In my case this won't do the job since I need one TIME_FIELD in SELECT but the GROUP BY must be either YEAR,MONTH,DAY or YEAR,MONTH or YEAR.

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using IF and having to repeat my query several times?

Comment: But MONTH and DAY are not in the group by.  @aggregation_zeit could be = 'mistake'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that DAY, MONTH, YEAR are numeric columns in your table, if not let me know and I'll change the answer.

```
SELECT   CASE 
             WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'day' THEN CAST(DATEFROMPARTS([YEAR], [MONTH], [DAY]) AS VARCHAR(12))
             WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'month' THEN STR([YEAR]) + '/' + STR([MONTH])
             WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'year' THEN STR([YEAR])
         END                                             AS TIME_FIELD,
FROM ...
GROUP BY CASE 
             WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'day' THEN CAST(DATEFROMPARTS([YEAR], [MONTH], [DAY]) AS VARCHAR(12))
             WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'month' THEN STR([YEAR]) + '/' + STR([MONTH])
             WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'year' THEN STR([YEAR])
         END
```

Comment: good idea! I had some issues with sorting (leading zeros) and extra whitespaces. RIGHT('0'+LTRIM(RTRIM(STR([TAG]))),2) did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is:

```
SELECT   [YEAR],
         CASE WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'day' OR @aggregation_zeit = 'month' THEN [MONTH]
              ELSE NULL
         END AS [MONTH],
         CASE WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'day' THEN [DAY]
              ELSE NULL
         END AS [DAY]
FROM ...
GROUP BY [YEAR],  
         CASE WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'day' OR @aggregation_zeit = 'month' THEN [MONTH]
              ELSE NULL
         END AS [MONTH],
         CASE WHEN @aggregation_zeit = 'day' THEN [DAY]
              ELSE NULL
         END AS [DAY]
```